# Error Using yaml-cpp in ROS?

Tags: yaml-cpp, ros

I am trying to use the yaml-cpp and according to the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/yaml_cpp), it's a system dependency so we don't even need to change the CMakelists.txt or manifest.xml. However, when I compile the code, I still get errors like:

```
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:53: undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::Parser(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:54: undefined reference to `YAML::Node::Node()'
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to `YAML::Node::~Node()'
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::~Parser()'
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to `YAML::Node::~Node()'
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::~Parser()'
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to `YAML::Node::~Node()'
/home/aramus/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/image_test/src/image_test.cpp:92: undefined reference to `YAML::Parser::~Parser()'
```

The only code I've added to CMakeLists.txt are:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} yaml-cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(image_test src/image_test.cpp)
```

I am using fuerte in Linux. Any solutions anybody?

EDIT:
I have found my solution! I changed my CMakeLists.txt to build the executable first then add the yaml-cpp library!

```
rosbuild_add_executable(image_test src/image_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(image_test yaml-cpp)
```

Those two lines in my CMakeLists.txt work fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are linker errors. Make sure you're linking to the library as well as including its headers. From the link you provided, it appears that in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, you need:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} yaml-cpp)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that line at the end and it now works wonders! I originally had it before the rosbuild_add_executable code and that screwed me over big time.